# PHPmyadmin upgrade / Loading forever while access any db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am trying to upgrade phpmyadmin on hosted server. I have asked to my hosting provider company they said me that, I manually need to upgrade phpmyadmin by using,
 server's command line using the following command:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/updatephpmyadmin
```

my concern is where can write those thing on hosted server. ?

I am new php developer and this is my first experience with hosting site.
On host server when ever I try to access any db "Loading" remain forever. phpmyadmin version on hosted server is 4.0.10.7 (lasted one is 4.4.10)

Some people claiming same issue resolved by upgrading phpmyadmin to latest version. So I think upgrading phpmyadmin might solve my issue as well.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Problem Solved:
It's happening because in whom/cpanel password i have "Pound" symbol which is not accepted on all system. I have just change password with standard symbols and all working now....

Even I dont need to upgrade my phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

For all who also have faced this issue,

It might be possible that in your channel/whm password you have used very special character (I have used "Pound" symbol which is not accepted in all system. I think we should stick to use standard symbol which are printed on keyboard.)

I have change my password and all working. Hope this information will help other as well.

Thanks